# What's the origin of the "-mente" postfix? Is it connected to the "mente" substantive?

Tags: etymology, adverbs

What's the origin of the rule that composes the adverbial forms finishing in *-mente* (e.g. *velocemente*, *normalmente*, *assolutamente*, *diversamente* etc).

Is it somehow connected to *mente* (Latin *mens*, English *mind*) substantive?

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting *absolutamente* in *assolutamente*, and of substituting *diversamente* for *altrimente* (which is an ancient form for present-day *altrimenti*).

Comment: @DaG why did you correct "altrimente" with "diversamente" and not "altrimenti"?

Comment: @martina: Simply because, even if its etymology is the same, not being a word in “-mente” it could be a bit confusing.

Comment: This is a very interesting question with two very interesting answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is. It continues the ablative form of Latin *mens*, which is indeed *mente*. So *felicemente* would have started meaning something like “in a happy state of mind.” (See for example the [Treccani article about “-mente”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mente_res-efa0db69-0025-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/).)

Answer (score 9):

You are on the right track. It is indeed true that those words ending in *-mente*, which are always adverbs derived from adjectives, take their origin in the Latin *mens* (*mind*, but also *spirit*, *intelligence*, *thought*).

This is because in Latin itself, a construction like "A + mente" meant "with an A mind," where A is an adjective.

Starting from this, the word *mente* came, in Italian, to be attached directly to the adjective to create a new adverb.

#### Sources

- [Treccani on the formation of adverbs](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/formazione-degli-avverbi_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/)
- [Zanichelli on adverbs](http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=2072)